# Property '_id' does not exist on type '{}[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm c native and I'm studying JS, TS, ReactJs. I created an application for study purposes, I am sending from the backend a package like:

```
{_id: '624d9476a390104449255c45', email: 'JohnSpecial@gmail.com', username: 'JohnSpecial', userpass: '12345', __v: 0}.
```

In my frontend I use react and ts. The app is very simple: I use fetch to make requests to the backend. This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const App = () => {
  const [backendData, setbackendData] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/readData/12345')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Data Received ' + JSON.stringify(data[0]))
        var myArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[0]))
        console.log(myArr)
        setbackendData(myArr)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Mongodb React Typescript - Send Data
      <p></p>
      {typeof backendData._id === 'undefined' ? <p>Loading...</p> : backendData._id}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I was using react and javascript and it was working. When I started using TS it started to look like this error message:
Property '_id' does not exist on type '{}[]'.

How can I show this JSON on my browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to tell typescript what type of data will be stored in the `useState` hook.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

interface BackendData {
  _id: number;
}

export const App = () => {
  const [backendData, setbackendData] = useState<BackendData | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/readData/12345')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setbackendData(data[0] as BackendData)
      })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Mongodb React Typescript - Send Data
      <p></p>
      {backendData ? backendData._id : <p>Loading...</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgKIBmZSG2RSAyjCjEnAL5xlQQhwDkUqDLwBQw4ADtmUMuhYAhdAGsk4gCYARJilzC4cAPrBVALjjj8IAEZIoAbmGtRSAB6RYcNBHGF4AQTBgcAC8cAAUAJTBAHw6ep7e8ADalkoqGlrYxDApaMpqmowAusEExAxMSAA8CrlpBdoAPmb4ADYtUaHmbeGierTklBihEdGxehxIMGgAFqG8APQCKOmM8wCMAEwAzAAsAKy8PePjAHQw0yrDAoSQ3kiRQTHXt8QnAFaEXhFHx3BnF+JhqotA8YjhdL89FkcnkVihQsDGIkAAzFFCEOA1WH1H7HVg-VjYRKFHoQgQwfBQcRhCF6SqqYAANw8LXRhAAcigQEgggAifxgXlRWnjACyXgA5hBVJZEIJ4AAVACeYCQhDQUGAYHgAFo4HQ0nB6iK6WAopV5maTbgYXUtHAAPxwW35LQnQyqOCmSpmgAyEGWEglJxDFrNjmOFoZjOFeh6rCAA)

Comment: and also probably need to tell the compiler that the reponse to JSON.parse (in this sepecific case) is type BackendData. Also not sure why OP is stringifying the object and then parsing it back to an object.

Comment: @Samathingamajig you're right. There are some really odd business logic in OP:s snipped.

Comment: Prefect, thanks friend.

Comment: @MarcioLafourcade please feel free to accept my answer by clicking on the check-mark next to the vote buttons. This will let other users know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your `backendData` has type `{}[]`. You need to properly type it. Example:

```js
interface BackendData {
  _id: number;
}
```